# Threejs 3D model implementation on Drupal

Tags: drupal, threejs-editor

I am completely new to Drupal and Three.js, and I need help with implementing a Three.js 3D model in my Drupal website. I have created the 3D model using a 3D modeling software and exported it as a .glb or .gltf file format, which is compatible with Three.js.

However, I have no idea how to add the necessary Three.js library files to my Drupal website or how to display the 3D model on a web page or content type.

I would greatly appreciate it if someone could provide me with a beginner's guide or step-by-step instructions on how to implement a Three.js 3D model in Drupal. Any resources, tutorials, or examples that you could recommend would also be very helpful.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Best regards,

I downloaded the .glTF now I just do know where to go from here.

Answer (score 1):

Add the Google model viewer module to Drupal. As long as you upload your gltf in a zip file it will display it

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).